# Writing a high order function to capture common pattern haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
f1 [] = 1
f1 (x:xs) = x * f1 xs

f2 [] = 0
f2 (x:xs) = 1 + f2 xs

f3 [] = 0
f3 (x:xs) = x + f3 xs

f4 [] = []
f4 (x:xs) = x ++ f4 xs
```

These all have a common behavior, how exactly can I identify the pattern and write a high order function to capture it?

Comment: Write a function with the pattern and add a parameter for everything that is different in your cases. (Bonus tip: use a function as a parameter for everything that is too different)

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered [Monoids](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid)! Or [folds](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=foldr), depending on your perspective.

Comment: These are called *folds*.

Comment: Lookup `foldr` and `foldl`.

Comment: We can even generalize this further: this is in fact a *catamorphism*.

Comment: Are congratulations in order? It looks like a homework assignment...

Comment: @user633183 Nope, revision for an exam that I have next week; took some sample questions from previous years to try

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All* your functions have the form:

```
fn [] = P_0
fn (x:xs) = P_1 x (fn xs)
```

Where `P_0` and `P_1` are some constants. I'll call `P_0` `zero`, and `P_1` `combine`, and add them to the function:

```
-- P_0  P_1     list   = result
fn zero _       []     = zero
fn zero combine (x:xs) = combine x (fn zero combine xs)
```

There we go. Now we have `f1 = fn 1 (*)`, `f3 = fn 0 (+)`, and `f4 = fn [] (++)`. `f2` is a little weird, but you can work it out: `f2 = fn 0 (\_ b -> b+1)`.

Asking GHCi the type gives us that `fn :: b -> (a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b`, and [Hoogling](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=b+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+b) shows us that this function `fn` is actually the function `foldr`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
--       ^combine         ^zero
```

So there you go: folds, or particularly *right* folds (the `r` in `foldr` means right) is the general pattern you're looking for.

By the way, there are also *left* folds. I'll leave you to try to work out what those might be. Hoogle could also help you here.

There's another pattern you could see here, called Monoids, but I'll also leave that to you, since it seems out of scope for this question.

---

* This may look weird for `f2 (x:xs) = 1 + f2 xs`, because there isn't an `x` involved in the result, but this is just the case where `P_1 a b = 1 + b`, which is still technically the same form.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you can use foldr to represent all of them.

```
foldr (*) 1 [1,2,3]  --f1

foldr (\_ a-> 1 + a) 0 [1,2,3]  --f2

foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]  --f3

foldr (++) [] ["a","b","c"]  --f4
```

They all need a list, an init value and an operator.
They all apply the operator from right to left: e.g `f1 [1,2,3]  = 1*2*(3*1)`
So you can use [`foldr`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldr_f.html) to parameterize the operator and the init value.

Comment: `foldr (\_ a -> a + 1) 0 $ [1,2,3]` might be a slightly easier-to-recognise/digest version of `f2`, rather than using `map (const 1)`.